# UseEffect causes infinite loop with swipeable routes

Tags: reactjs

I am using the https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-swipeable-routes library to set up some swipeable views in my React app.

I have a custom context that contains a dynamic list of views that need to be rendered as children of the swipeable router, and I have added two buttons for a 'next' and 'previous' view for desktop users.

Now I am stuck on how to get the next and previous item from the array of modules.

I thought to fix it with a custom context and custom hook, but when using that I am getting stuck in an infinite loop.

My custom hook:

```
import { useContext } from 'react';
import { RootContext } from '../context/root-context';

const useShow = () => {
  const [state, setState] = useContext(RootContext);

  const setModules = (modules) => {
    setState((currentState) => ({
      ...currentState,
      modules,
    }));
  };

  const setActiveModule = (currentModule) => {
    // here is the magic. we get the currentModule, so we know which module is visible on the screen
    // with this info, we can determine what the previous and next modules are
    const index = state.modules.findIndex((module) => module.id === currentModule.id);

    // if we are on first item, then there is no previous
    let previous = index - 1;
    if (previous < 0) {
      previous = 0;
    }

    // if we are on last item, then there is no next
    let next = index + 1;
    if (next > state.modules.length - 1) {
      next = state.modules.length - 1;
    }

    // update the state. this will trigger every component listening to the previous and next values
    setState((currentState) => ({
      ...currentState,
      previous: state.modules[previous].id,
      next: state.modules[next].id,
    }));
  };

  return {
    modules: state.modules,
    setActiveModule,
    setModules,
    previous: state.previous,
    next: state.next,
  };
};

export default useShow;
```

My custom context:

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';

export const RootContext = React.createContext([{}, () => {}]);

export default (props) => {
  const [state, setState] = useState({});

  return (
    <RootContext.Provider value={[state, setState]}>
      {props.children}
    </RootContext.Provider>
  );
};
```

and here the part where it goes wrong, in my Content.js

```
import React, { useEffect } from 'react';
import { Route } from 'react-router-dom';
import SwipeableRoutes from 'react-swipeable-routes';
import useShow from '../../hooks/useShow';
import NavButton from '../NavButton';

// for this demo we just have one single module component
// when we have real data, there will be a VoteModule and CommentModule at least
// there are 2 important object given to the props; module and match
// module comes from us, match comes from swipeable views library
const ModuleComponent = ({ module, match }) => {
  // we need this function from the custom hook
  const { setActiveModule } = useShow();

  // if this view is active (match.type === 'full') then we tell the show hook that
  useEffect(() => {
    if (match.type === 'full') {
      setActiveModule(module);
    }
  },[match]);

  return (
    <div style={{ height: 300, backgroundColor: module.title }}>{module.title}</div>
  );
};

const Content = () => {
  const { modules, previousModule, nextModule } = useShow();

  // this is a safety measure, to make sure we don't start rendering stuff when there are no modules yet
  if (!modules) {
    return <div>Loading...</div>;
  }

  // this determines which component needs to be rendered for each module
  // when we have real data we will switch on module.type or something similar
  const getComponentForModule = (module) => {
    // this is needed to get both the module and match objects inside the component
    // the module object is provided by us and the match object comes from swipeable routes
    const ModuleComponentWithProps = (props) => (
      <ModuleComponent module={module} {...props} />
    );

    return ModuleComponentWithProps;
  };

  // this renders all the modules
  // because we return early if there are no modules, we can be sure that here the modules array is always existing
  const renderModules = () => (
    modules.map((module) => (
      <Route
        path={`/${module.id}`}
        key={module.id}
        component={getComponentForModule(module)}
        defaultParams={module}
      />
    ))
  );

  return (
    <div className="content">
      <div>
        <SwipeableRoutes>
          {renderModules()}
        </SwipeableRoutes>
        <NavButton type="previous" to={previousModule} />
        <NavButton type="next" to={nextModule} />
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Content;
```

For sake of completion, also my NavButton.js :

```
import React from 'react';
import { NavLink } from 'react-router-dom';

const NavButton = ({ type, to }) => {
  const iconClassName = ['fa'];
  if (type === 'next') {
    iconClassName.push('fa-arrow-right');
  } else {
    iconClassName.push('fa-arrow-left');
  }
  return (
    <div className="">
      <NavLink className="nav-link-button" to={`/${to}`}>
        <i className={iconClassName.join(' ')} />
      </NavLink>
    </div>
  );
};

export default NavButton;
```

In Content.js there is this part:

```
// if this view is active (match.type === 'full') then we tell the show hook that
  useEffect(() => {
    if (match.type === 'full') {
      setActiveModule(module);
    }
  },[match]);
```

which is causing the infinite loop. If I comment out the setActiveModule call, then the infinite loop is gone, but of course then I also won't have the desired outcome.

I am sure I am doing something wrong in either the usage of useEffect and/or the custom hook I have created, but I just can't figure out what it is.

Any help is much appreciated

Answer (score 0):

I think it's the problem with the way you are using the component in the Route. 
Try using:

```
<Route
    path={`/${module.id}`}
    key={module.id}
    component={() => getComponentForModule(module)}
    defaultParams={module}
/>
```

**EDIT:**

I have a feeling that it's because of your HOC. 
Can you try

```
component={ModuleComponent}
defaultParams={module}
```

And get the module from the match object.

```
const ModuleComponent = ({ match }) => {
  const {type, module} = match;
  const { setActiveModule } = useShow();

  useEffect(() => {
    if (type === 'full') {
      setActiveModule(module);
    }
  },[module, setActiveModule]);
```

Comment: tried, but that gives me the following error: "Warning: Functions are not valid as a React child. This may happen if you return a Component instead of <Component /> from render. Or maybe you meant to call this function rather than return it.
    in component (created by SwipeableRoutes)"

Comment: Scratch that. That wouldn't work. 

Updated the answer, can you check that.

Answer (score 0):

`match` is an object and evaluated in the useEffect will always cause the code to be executed. Track `match.type` instead. Also you need to track the module there. If that's an object, you'll need to wrap it in a deep compare hook: https://github.com/kentcdodds/use-deep-compare-effect

```
useEffect(() => {
    if (match.type === 'full') {
      setActiveModule(module);
    }
  },[match.type, module]);
```